# My app does not recognize react-bootstrap styles

Tags: reactjs, import, styles, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap

I am trying to make an app with react. I want to use react bootstrap. I downloaded bootstrap and react bootstrap in the project.
`

```
npm i bootstrap@5.2.3
```

`

`

```
npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

`

this is my package.json:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbCcf.png)

I have imported the css in the App.js, I have also tried to import it in the index.js, but it still doesn't recognize it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2rAe.png)

I have copied the link in the index.html of the public folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkTlw.png)

when importing react bootstrap components I have done the imports for each component, but it doesn't recognize the styles, my 'card' looks like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqnzo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUOBZ.png)

I don't know if I'm missing some import, or some npm to do. I have changed the imports of site a thousand times and it still does not work. does anyone know what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

1.) install bootstrap from npm package

```
npm install bootstrap
```

2.) Open your index file (Index.js) and have these two lines there like so

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; //<-- Add this 
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min'; // <-- Add this 

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))

reportWebVitals();
```

3.) Add button to see if Bootstrap button does show in App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
        <a className="btn btn-primary"
             data-bs-toggle="collapse"
             href="#collapseExample"
             role="button"
             aria-expanded="false"
             aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Bootstrap button
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

4.) Run app with npm start and see if your bootstrap has been installed and ready to go. My case

[image: bootstrap.png]

Comment: The button is displayed correctly, but the Card for some reason still looks the same as in the picture. Could it be that it needs extra imports ?

Comment: @macarenafernandez-ayuso check https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap5/bootstrap_cards.php

Comment: please give it a like if it answers your question :)

Comment: @macarenafernandez-ayuso did it solve ur problem?

Comment: no, it has not solved it. The Cards are not recognized, just like at the beginning. Other components are recognized, such as the Navbar or the Button. Thank you.

Comment: @macarenafernandez-ayuso have you taken a look at something like this? https://www.javatpoint.com/react-bootstrap-cards

Comment: @macarenafernandez-ayuso You can also see this as second reference https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-react-bootstrap-with-npm